# Persist view controller state in SWRevealViewConttoller in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using `SWRevealViewController` for navigation drawer in iOS.I have one main screen which is shown by default when app launches.I have also other screens like Settings,Help,About. So when user switch between screens then state of 1st view controller is reset.I want to persist it's state lie if was showing some data in screen then it should not get removed.

I am using below code to switch between screens.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"home" sender:cell];
        [cell setSelected:YES];
    }

    else if(indexPath.row==1)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"settings" sender:cell];
    }

    else if(indexPath.row==2)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"help" sender:cell];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row==3)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@“about” sender:cell];
    }

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Segue");
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    UINavigationController *destViewController = (UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.title = [[titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] capitalizedString];
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"settings"])
    {
        self.revealViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Settings";

    }
    else  if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"help"])
    {
        self.revealViewController.navigationItem.title = @"help";
    }
    else  if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"about"])
    {
        self.revealViewController.navigationItem.title = @"about";
    }

    if([segue isKindOfClass:[SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]])
    {
        SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

        swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {
            UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
            [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];



        };

    }

  }
```

One solution I see that to keep the viewController in the navigation stack so that the viewController not get destroyed it remains in the stack when user go to "home" then it is relaunched from navigation stack instead of initializing the view controller again.

Comment: Why you did not use what you have suggested as solution?

Comment: I am not able to understand how to use this with swrevealviewcontroller.

Comment: You can keep reference of your view controllers in the side menu's vc

Comment: can you please provide the code for this or maybe explain more..

Answer (score 0):

For example for HelpVC , you store a property of it in your side mennu view controller:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) HelpViewContoller* helpVC;
```

Than in row selection instead of calling your segue, you instantiate the view controller, but before that you check if it is instantiated already you use it:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if(indexPath.row==0) {
    if (helpVC == nil) {
        helpVC =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"helpVCidentifier"];
        [self changeFrontVCto:helpVC];
    }
}   
 }


-(void) changeFrontVCto:(UIViewController*)vc {
UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
[navController setViewControllers: @[vc] animated: NO ];
[self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
}
```